# Pandas: Find index of the row with second highest value

Tags: python, pandas

I am trying to get the index of the row with the second highest value after doing groupby but I am not getting the right result

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'Sp':['a','b','c','d','e','f'], 'Mt':['s1', 's1', 's2','s2','s2','s3'], 'Value':[1,2,3,4,5,6], 'count':[3,2,5,10,10,6]})
```

Doing this

```
df.iloc[df.groupby(['Mt'])['Value'].apply(lambda x: (x!=max(x)).idxmax())]
```

is returning

```
    Mt  Sp  Value   count
0   s1  a   1   3
2   s2  c   3   5
5   s3  f   6   6
```

For group s2 , index 3 of the original dataframe should be returned.

Answer (score 4):

Since 'Value' is already sorted you can use [`nth`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.nth.html):

```
In [11]: g = df.groupby("Mt", as_index=False)

In [12]: g.nth(-2)
Out[12]:
   Mt Sp  Value  count
0  s1  a      1      3
3  s2  d      4     10
```

Otherwise I'd first sort by Value, `df = df.sort_values("Value")`.

If you want the last (if there are fewer than two in a given group), you could grab that too

```
In [21]: g = df.groupby("Mt")

In [22]: res = g.nth(-1)

In [23]: res.update(g.nth(-2))

In [24]: res
Out[24]:
   Sp  Value  count
Mt
s1  a      1      3
s2  d      4     10
s3  f      6      6
```

---

A related function is [`tail`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.tail.html) (to get the last two elements):

```
In [31]: g.tail(2)
Out[31]:
   Mt Sp  Value  count
0  s1  a      1      3
1  s1  b      2      2
3  s2  d      4     10
4  s2  e      5     10
5  s3  f      6      6
```

Answer (score 0):

OK I got the answer except for one thing. This code seems to work

```
df.iloc[df.groupby(['Mt'])['Value'].apply(lambda x: (x!=max(x)).order(ascending=False).head(1).index[0])]
```

The only thing I dont understand right now that even with a group of one row only that row is being returned. I was thinking that may be `x!=max(x)` check would exclude that row.